# Angular conditionally show messages based on multiple case

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I have an issue finding the best way to show a message based on multiple conditions.

I have an object like this in a file called `messages.ts` :

```
export const VALIDATION_MESSAGES = { // Around 15 messages
 message1: 'message1',
 message2: 'message2',
 message3: 'message3',
 message4: 'message4',
 ...
}
```

And I have a function that return me an array or required data like so :

```
// Example 1
[  
 'EM',
 'PL'
]

// Example 2
[  
 'AP',
 'PL',
 'EMP'
]
```

I have around 10 combinations, each combination is releated to a message in my `messages.ts`, for example `['EM', 'PL']` is related to message2, etc...

On `ngOnInit` I call a function to control the message to show and assign it to `this.message` of my component.

But I can't find the best way to do that function in a clean modern javascript/typescript way.

Thank in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom pipe and pass the array to it and return the message from the transform method based on your conditions